# How to find error in apk successuflly installed on phone?

Tags: android, kotlin, apk

I create an Android app with Kotlin, It run successuflly without any error on android studio emulator, when I generate the apk, and I install it in my android device, It install aslo successuflly, and I can run it but my problem is for example  when I click on some button in some UI an error appear  for example the activity didn't appear, However on an android studio emulator  work .
I try to debug my code in my device, I couldn't find any error or problem.
So, I would like to ask If there's a tool to find the error in apk successuflly installed on phone ?

Comment: If the application is not running on your device, you should enable debugging in the developer options so that you can get output through logcat in Android Studio.  It's not clear from your post if you have already done this.  Once you have logcat working you may want to disable filters if the problem is coming from outside the code

Comment: The application running in my device, but there's features work on an emulator like when I click on button a new activity opened (an example) However It not work on device (I mean the activity not opened), I want to know where's the problem? How can I find the error,if I find the error my problem is solved

Comment: Follow my comment above and use logcat.  That will let you find the error on your device.

Comment: I activate the debugging in the developer options as you said and I debug my app with my device from the android studio but no error appear hear only when I installed the apk in the device

Comment: I got the following error "could not compute caller for function : public constructor CampaignData(name:Kotlin.String?=...) defined in package [Deserialized ClassConstructorDescriptor](member=null)"

Comment: I think this question has been resolved if you can get the error now.  Consider opening a new question for the above error